# swift ios9 : if tab already selected, switch the current tab to another when clicking on it

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

Ok so here is the thing, i have an app with a tabbarcontroller.
I have four tabs on this tabbarcontroller (test1, test3, test4, test5).
If i am already on the first tab, when i select it, i want this tab to change from test1 to test2.
Currently i managed to change the title, but for actually reload the view i have to switch to one of the other tabs and come back.
I'm struggling on this issue for quite a while now and i can't seem to find where i failed.

Here is the code of the controller link with my four tabs:
http://pastebin.com/tvJ0PYvR

and here is the code link to my tabbarcontroller :
http://pastebin.com/jSw8dPfJ

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the answer, almost find it when looking for how to refresh a view
http://pastebin.com/w88m5M0Y
What one needs to do is deleting the view after detecting the selection (when already on the tab) and recreating the view to display the new one (switching from test1 to test 2 on first tab)

Put this in your didSelectItem function :

self.viewDidDisappear(false)

self.viewWillAppear(true)